# Four coins in a quarter circle frame: can the coins move?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, geometry

Four equal size smooth circular coins are in a quarter circle frame. In the beginning, the centres of the coins are the vertices of a square, with two coins each touching a straight edge of the frame, and the other two coins each touching the arc of the frame.

[image]

> Can the coins move, either individually or [simultaneously](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4611295/398708)?

Obviously each coin can rotate about its own centre; I'm referring to translation.

I [asked this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4615358/398708) on Math Stack Exchange, but did not receive a satisfactory answer, so I thought I would see if there is a physics-related way to answer this question.

(I asked some of my math colleagues at school, and they told me it's a physics question so I should go ask the physics teachers. So I asked the physics teachers, and they told me it's a math question, so I should go ask the math teachers.)

Comment: This is a Mathematics question and there are three answers on the MSE site although not in agreement!  It is a question which needs Geometry to provide an answer.

Comment: This is geometric problem not physic problem